# Change Background Image Between Certain Times

Tags: c#, datetime, background

I have a website where I want the background to change between: 18:00 and 06:00 (7PM and 6AM). I have tried a solution using `DateTime`, but I can't get it to work:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    int intTime = DateTime.Today.TimeOfDay;

    if (intTime >= 1300 && intTime <= 0600) {
        ImgNatPic.ImageUrl = "img/jantelov.jpg";
    }
}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: `TimeOfDay` is a `TimeSpan` not an `int`. This doesn't even compile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[TimeOfDay](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofday) returns a TimeSpan not an int. On [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan) you have an Hours  property that gives you what you need.

```
    TimeSpan time = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay; 

    if ((time.Hours >= 18) || (time.Hours <= 6)) 
    { 
        ImgNatPic.ImageUrl = "img/jantelov.jpg"; 
    }
```

Comment: Probably want to use `DateTime.Now` since `Today` is always at midnight.

Answer (score 3):

`DateTime.Today.TimeOfDay` returns Timespan, not int!

The easiest way to achieve it is to use `DateTime.Now.Hour` so it would look like:

```
int time = DateTime.Now.Hour
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;` rather than `.Today` as the `.Today` property contains only the date with the time set to midnight.

Also `.TimeOfDay` returns a `TimeSpan` not an `int`, so you need to adjust your if statement accordingly.  If you are only interested in the hours component, you can use `DateTime.Now.Hour` which will return an hour.